# ArgoCD can not understand escape character in Github pipeline

Tags: github-actions, argocd

I have a question related to deploying my application by ArgoCD in the Github pipeline:
I'm using "`clowdhaus/argo-cd-action/@main`" action in my pipeline, and when I want to change my ingress values by Argo CLI, with the below command:

```
argocd app create my-app  --server <something> --auth-token ${{ secrets.ARGO_PR_TOKEN }} --repo <something> --release-name <something> --path helm/my-app --dest-namespace staging --dest-server <something> --values ingress_values.yaml --helm-set ingress.enabled=true --helm-set ingress.hosts\[0\].host=my_values --sync-policy automated --auto-prune --self-heal --upsert
```

but the values in `ingress.hosts[0].host` should use escape character, which I used `\` so the result in Argo panel is showing like this `ingress.hosts\[0\].host` , which is not correct. the result should not be with `\` , the escape character is only used here for the pipeline.

I already used **single quotations** or **double quotations** but none of them worked.

[image]

I appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Argo CD is happy to take a parameter like `list[0]=something`. Just make sure you escape the parameter appropriately for whatever shell you're using.

In BASH, for example, single-quoting the literal value should work fine.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

argocd app create my-app \
  --server SOMETHING \
  --auth-token ${{ secrets.ARGO_PR_TOKEN }} \
  --repo SOMETHING \
  --release-name SOMETHING \
  --path helm/my-app \
  --dest-namespace staging \
  --dest-server SOMETHING \
  --values ingress_values.yaml \
  --helm-set ingress.enabled=true \
  --helm-set 'ingress.hosts[0].host=my_values' \
  --sync-policy automated \
  --auto-prune \
  --self-heal \
  --upsert
```

Answer (score 0):

how I solved this issue:

I used `--helm-set-string` without using any escape character, like this:

```
  argocd app create my-app \
  --server SOMETHING \
  --auth-token ${{ secrets.ARGO_PR_TOKEN }} \
  --repo SOMETHING \
  --release-name SOMETHING \
  --path helm/my-app \
  --dest-namespace staging \
  --dest-server SOMETHING \
  --values ingress_values.yaml \
  --helm-set ingress.enabled=true \
  --helm-set-string ingress.hosts[0].host=my_values \
  --sync-policy automated \
  --auto-prune \
  --self-heal \
  --upsert
```